# Leitura de Array

Tags: javascript

Recebo de uma API o seguinte resultado:

```
{
   "ShippingSevicesArray":[
      {
         "ServiceCode":"3",
         "ServiceDescription":"Transportadora Jadlog ",
         "Carrier":"Jadlog",
         "ShippingPrice":"12.09",
         "DeliveryTime":"3",
         "Msg":"Valor do Frete",
         "Error":false,
         "OriginalDeliveryTime":"3",
         "OriginalShippingPrice":"12.09",
         "ResponseTime":"371.2847"
      },
      {
         "ServiceCode":"DAY_1",
         "ServiceDescription":"Daytona Express",
         "Carrier":"Daytona Express",
         "ShippingPrice":"17.59",
         "DeliveryTime":"1",
         "Msg":"Ok",
         "Error":false,
         "OriginalDeliveryTime":"1",
         "OriginalShippingPrice":"17.590600",
         "ResponseTime":"542.6267"
      },
      {
         "ServiceCode":"04596",
         "ServiceDescription":"PAC (04596)",
         "Carrier":"Correios",
         "ShippingPrice":"18.72",
         "DeliveryTime":"5",
         "Msg":"Não foi encontrada precificação. ERP-013: Valor declarado nao permitido (valor minimo: 19,5, valor maximo: 3000)(-1).",
         "Error":false,
         "OriginalDeliveryTime":"5",
         "OriginalShippingPrice":"18.720000",
         "ResponseTime":"749.0625"
      },
      {
         "ServiceCode":"04553",
         "ServiceDescription":"Sedex (04553)",
         "Carrier":"Correios",
         "ShippingPrice":"22.23",
         "DeliveryTime":"2",
         "Msg":"Não foi encontrada precificação. ERP-013: Valor declarado nao permitido (valor minimo: 19,5, valor maximo: 10000)(-1).",
         "Error":false,
         "OriginalDeliveryTime":"2",
         "OriginalShippingPrice":"22.230000",
         "ResponseTime":"295.264"
      }
   ],
   "Timeout":0
}
```

Mas não estou conseguindo fazer a leitura como JavaScript, estou usando o seguinte código:

```
var person = json; //json tem o conteúdo acima                        
var i = 0;
var itens = '';                        
var len = person.length;
for (; i < len; ) {     
    itens += '<li>'+person["ShippingSevicesArray"][i]["ServiceDescription"]+'</li>';
    i++                           
}

$("#frete").append(itens);
```

Esta retornando o erro:

```
"Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
```

algum sugestão de como resolver?

Apliquei vários exemplos encontrados na internet mas não tive sucesso.

Comment: O que acontece se você fazer um `console.log` no `json`? O console loga um objeto ou uma string no formato json? Outro erro no código é que `len` deveria receber o valor de `person.ShippingSevicesArray.length`, não `person.length`, mas isso não é o que está ocasionando o seu erro.

Comment: ele traz exatamente a informação que coloquei acima {"ShippingSevicesArray":......

Comment: Sim, ele traz a informação, mas é possível que essa informação esteja no formato de uma string, o que justificaria o erro que você está tendo, pois ao tentar acessar a propriedade `ShippingSevicesArray` de uma string você receberia `undefined`, e ao tentar acessar a propriedade `0` de `undefined`, você receberia o erro `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro não é reproduzível, então pela mensagem de erro vou tentar deduzir o erro.

`json` ser estar vindo como uma string. Isso significa que não é possível acessar a propriedade `ShippingSevicesArray` de `json`. Primeiro você deveria fazer o parse dessa string para converte-la num objeto, para então acessar suas propriedades, da seguinte maneira:

```js
var person = JSON.parse(json);
```

Agora `person` recebe um objeto, e você pode acessar suas propriedades normalmente.

```js
var i = 0;
var itens = '';                        
var len = person.ShippingSevicesArray.length;

for (; i < len; ) {     
    itens += '<li>'+person.ShippingSevicesArray[i].ServiceDescription+'</li>';
    i++                           
}
$("#frete").append(itens);
```

Ou de forma mais breve

```js
var itens = person.ShippingSevicesArray.map(ss => `<li>${ss.ServiceDescription}</li>`);
$("#frete").append(itens);
```

Comment: Sim foi isso mesmo estava vindo como string e eu não me atentei a isso.

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Precisa pegar o valor de quantidade de itens da lista pela propriedade `ShippingSevicesArray`, exemplo:

```
person.ShippingSevicesArray.length
```

e depois utilizar o mesmo código:

```js
const person = {"ShippingSevicesArray":[{"ServiceCode":"3","ServiceDescription":"Transportadora Jadlog ","Carrier":"Jadlog","ShippingPrice":"12.09","DeliveryTime":"3","Msg":"Valor do Frete","Error":false,"OriginalDeliveryTime":"3","OriginalShippingPrice":"12.09","ResponseTime":"371.2847"},{"ServiceCode":"DAY_1","ServiceDescription":"Daytona Express","Carrier":"Daytona Express","ShippingPrice":"17.59","DeliveryTime":"1","Msg":"Ok","Error":false,"OriginalDeliveryTime":"1","OriginalShippingPrice":"17.590600","ResponseTime":"542.6267"},{"ServiceCode":"04596","ServiceDescription":"PAC (04596)","Carrier":"Correios","ShippingPrice":"18.72","DeliveryTime":"5","Msg":"Não foi encontrada precificação. ERP-013: Valor declarado nao permitido (valor minimo: 19,5, valor maximo: 3000)(-1).","Error":false,"OriginalDeliveryTime":"5","OriginalShippingPrice":"18.720000","ResponseTime":"749.0625"},{"ServiceCode":"04553","ServiceDescription":"Sedex (04553)","Carrier":"Correios","ShippingPrice":"22.23","DeliveryTime":"2","Msg":"Não foi encontrada precificação. ERP-013: Valor declarado nao permitido (valor minimo: 19,5, valor maximo: 10000)(-1).","Error":false,"OriginalDeliveryTime":"2","OriginalShippingPrice":"22.230000","ResponseTime":"295.264"}],"Timeout":0};

                     
var i = 0;
var itens = '';                        
var len = person.ShippingSevicesArray.length;

for (; i < len; ) {     
    itens += '<li>'+person["ShippingSevicesArray"][i]["ServiceDescription"]+'</li>';
    i++                           
}

$("#items").html(itens);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="items"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para o seu código funcionar, apenas substitua:

```
var len = person.length;
```

Por:

```
var len = Object.keys(person).length;
```